# Where is the verse ''sahasra-namnam punyanam... prayacchati'' found?

Tags: shloka, identification-request, vishnu-sahasranama

> sahasra-namnam punyanam, trir-avrttya tu yat phalam;
>   
> ekavrttya tu krsnasya, namaikam tat prayacchati
>
> Meaning: If one utters shri-krishna-nama once, one obtains the same
>   result that comes from chanting the pure visnu-sahasranama
>   three times.

Where is the above verse found?

Many websites claim the above verse is found in the Brahmanda Purana while some say the Brahma Vaivarta Purana.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is 19th verse in **Chapter 36 Upodhgatapada of Brahmanda Purana**. Sesha says this to Dharani (Goddess Earth) ([Translated](https://archive.org/stream/BrahmandaPurana_37/BrahmandaPurana-G.v.tagare-Part2#page/n287/mode/2up) by GV Tagore)

> सहस्रनाम्नां पुण्यानां त्रिरावृत्त्या तु यत्फलम्
>     एकावृत्त्या तु कृष्णस्य नामैकं तत्प्रयच्छति  १९
>
> sahasranāmnāṃ puṇyānāṃ trirāvṛttyā tu yatphalam 
> ekāvṛttyā tu kṛṣṇasya nāmaikaṃ tatprayacchati (19)
>
> By a simple repetition, a single name of Krsna  yields that fruit which is yielded by repeating three times the  thousand holy names.

Comment: The first word is not matching. Shouldn't this be Sa instead of ma?

Comment: @SreeCharan Check [here](http://gretil.sub.uni-goettingen.de/gretil/1_sanskr/3_purana/brndp2_u.htm).

Comment: I think this is a typo because स and म look same. They might have got confused. Sahasranamnam gives the correct meaning of thousand names instead of Mahasranamnam.