# Is there any scriptural proof that shri krishna's name is three times more powerful as of Shri Ram

Tags: puranas, gods, gaudiya-vaishnavism

I came across many gaudiya Vaishnavas saying such. Is there any scriptural proof??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where is it mentioned that chanting Krishna is more powerful than chanting Rama's name?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/31573/where-is-it-mentioned-that-chanting-krishna-is-more-powerful-than-chanting-rama)

Comment: AFAIK, there is no explicit statement which says so. There is one statement in brahmanda purana which says this kind of thing but it does not mentions the name 'Rama'.

Answer (score 2):

Padma Purana, 6.254. 20-29, conversation of Shiva Parvati—

> Lord Siva Says: “O Varānanā, I chant the holy name of Rāma, Rāma, Rāma and thus enjoy this beautiful sound. This holy name of Rāmacandra is equal to one thousand holy names of Lord Viṣṇu.

[Where is the verse ''sahasra-namnam punyanam... prayacchati'' found?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/19806/where-is-the-verse-sahasra-namnam-punyanam-prayacchati-found)

> It is 19th verse in Chapter 36 Upodhgatapada of Brahmanda Purana. Sesha says this to Dharani (Goddess Earth) (Translated by GV Tagore)

> > सहस्रनाम्नां पुण्यानां त्रिरावृत्त्या तु यत्फलम्
> > एकावृत्त्या तु कृष्णस्य नामैकं तत्प्रयच्छति १९

> > sahasranāmnāṃ puṇyānāṃ trirāvṛttyā tu yatphalam
> > ekāvṛttyā tu kṛṣṇasya nāmaikaṃ tatprayacchati (19)

> > By a simple repetition, a single name of Krsna yields that fruit which is yielded by repeating three times the thousand holy names

A simple inference implies that the name of Krishna is three times more powerful.

Comment: रामात् परतरं नास्ति किञ्चित जगत्त्रेय। Lomesh samhita
There is no word greater than Shri ram.